# C++/CLI: Implementing IList and IList<T> (explicit implementation of a default indexer)

Tags: c++-cli, indexer, explicit-interface

I am trying to implement a C++/CLI class that implements both `IList` and `IList<T>`.

Since they have overlapping names, I have to implement one of them explicitly, and the natural choice should be IList.

The implicit implementation of the indexer is:

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
generic<class InnerT> public ref class MyList : public System::Collections::IList, IList<InnerT> {
  // ...
  property InnerT default[int]{
    virtual InnerT get(int index);
    virtual void set(int index, InnerT item);
  }
}
```

I am now trying to declare the default indexer for IList.

My guess would be something like this:

```
  property Object^ System::Collections::IList::default[int]{
    virtual Object^ System::Collections::IList::get(int index);
    virtual void System::Collections::IList::set(int index, Object^ item);
  }
```

but that just gives me

> error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'default'

Any hints?

Comment: Please change "implements both IList and IList." to "implements both IList and IList<T>".

Comment: Thanks! It seems markdown was removing the <T>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JaredPar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689704/c-cli-implementing-ilist-and-ilistt-explicit-implementation-of-a-default-inde/689773#689773) almost worked. Two things should be changed:

- The indexer-property needs a different name since "default" is already taken by the implicit implementation.
- The specification of the overriding needs to be done on the set- and get-methods, not on the property itself.

I.e.:

```
  property Object^ IListItems[int]{
    virtual Object^ get(int index) = System::Collections::IList::default::get;
    virtual void set(int index, Object^ item)  = System::Collections::IList::default::set;
  }
```

Comment: Also relevant when going to implement the enumerator Current property:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=101089

Answer (score 2):

Haven't done a lot of interfaces in C++/CLI but this appears to be covered 8.8.10.1 of the [C++/CLI spec](http://www.plumhall.com/C++-CLI%20draft%201.5.pdf).  I believe the feature you're looking for is explicit overriding.  In this you must specify the implemented member after the definition like so.

```
property Object^ default[int] = System::Collections::IList::default {... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled a class implementing `IList<T>` explicitly written in C# and opened it with Reflector and disassembled to C++/CLI.

```
T System::Collections::Generic::IList<T>::get_Item(Int32 __gc* index)
{
   //
}

void __gc* System::Collections::Generic::IList<T>::set_Item(Int32 __gc* index, T value)
{
   //
}
```

But it doesn't compile: `get_Item`, `set_Item` is not a member of `IList<T>`;

Comment: Reflector disassembles into Managed C++ not C++/CLI. Managed C++ is the older managed code extensions.  You can tell by all the __gc pointers.

Comment: There is an extension to Reflector that can generate C++/CLI. Unfortunately, it also gave uncompilable code.